# Curve Fitting - DataSet

Tags: algorithm, interpolation, curve-fitting

I am given the following problem.

I have a Set of functions which are linear combinations of the following functions (f1,f2,f3....fn) and a noisy dataset of pairs  (x,y). I want to find a function from my set which approximates the dataset the best.
They key to finding the solution is to find coefficients a1,a2...an so that the resulting function f=a1*f1...an*fn approximates y well given the input x.
 If the data wasnt noisy, I could just choose 5 points and solve the resulting system of equations but I dont think this would work well with noisy data.

How would one find the coefficients ?

(I am asking for an algorithm and not for a program, for example matlab, that does the job for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In presence of noise you need to find some approximation solution, that minimizes discrepancies with ideal solution.
Such best fit problems are usually solved by optimization algorithms.

Widely used one is [Levenberg–Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) algorithm.